# How do I specify transpose in R?

Tags: r

I tried to do matrix computation. But, the transpose does not work. Is there any idea to solve the following situation?

```
D=matrix(rnorm(9),3,3))
S=c(1);   D[-S,]%*%as.matrix(D[S,])
S=c(1);   D[-S,]%*%t(as.matrix(D[S,]))    ## Error
S=c(1,2); D[-S,]%*%as.matrix(D[S,])       ## Error
S=c(1,2); D[-S,]%*%t(as.matrix(D[S,]))  
## I want to use the last expression both for S=1 and S=c(1,2)
```

Comment: for `S=c(1,2); D[-S,]%*%as.matrix(D[S,])`, you are multiplying a 1x3 matrix with a 2x3 matrix. What are the mathematical operations that you are trying to perform?

Comment: I only consider correct math operations like the second and fourth lines. I want to express them in one line without separating them.

Comment: not sure if i fully understand your needs. you can pass in `drop=FALSE` like `D[-S,,drop=FALSE]%*%t(as.matrix(D[S,,drop=FALSE]))`

Comment: I found that the following worked for S=c(1) and S=c(1,2): 

D[-S,]%*%t(as.matrix(D[S,,drop=FALSE]))

Thank you.